# VBA Break Command bound to a key

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to disable to the BREAK (or pause) key in VBA, but I have come up against 2 walls.

1. How do you tell VBA that the function key is being pressed
2. What is the On.Key {NAME} for interrupt?

My workbook forces users to have macros enabled by setting every sheet to xlVeryHidden when the workbook is closed, and setting them to visible when opened (and various other bits centered around logging in to certain areas of the workbook), meaning the VBA has to be used. However, at certain points in the "Workbook_open" routine, if someone interrupts the program, it leaves the login access vunerable and I do not want this.

I want to be able to bind the interrupt command to any key combination I desire, so only I know what it is, leaving the break key disabled.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via the command `Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled`.

[This link](http://www.databison.com/prevent-users-ctrl-break-ing-your-vba-code-during-execution/) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Using Manu's link, I resolved the problem by using this code:

```
On Error GoTo errorhandler
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler

'***Code that you don't want interupted goes here***

Exit Sub
errorhandler:
If Err.Number = 18 Then
Call error_handler_message
Resume
Else
MsgBox "Something went wrong!"
Exit Sub
End If
```

in the "error_handler_message" procedure is:

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
MsgBox "Breaking Of Code Execution Has Been Disabled", vbOKOnly, "Unable To Stop Process!"
```

The reason there is the `xlDisabled` is because without it, the user could press ctrl + break again and break that operation, if you disable it, they can't break the anti-break code too.